# pandas filter text in column according to data in other column

Tags: regex, pandas

I'm making prep of social media text data. The two columns look like this:

```
name                text
@dnsTV2             @raisa Bullshit!
Sebastian           @dnsTV2, are you kidding?
@raisa              @dnsTV2 thanks to corona...
imax468             @oksana what do you mean by that???
oksana              raisa! It is so true!
```

In 'text' the first one or two words are the nicknames of people the person is answering to in his comment (sometimes beginning with @, but not always). All nicknames persons are answering to are at some place in 'name' column because people are talking to each other.

My task is to delete this names and '@' from 'text' column while keeping the rest of the text.

Is there a way I could filter the text in the second column using the content of the first?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses regex. It takes all the names from the names column and removes the `@`. It then adds `@?` in front of them, which means optional `@`in regex. It then joins them all with `|`, which lets you pass them all to `Series.str.replace` function, replacing them with empty strings.
This assumes there is no consistency between the names that have `@` in the text column and in the name column. If there is, there is an even simpler solution.

```
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['@dnsTV2', 'Sebastian', '@raisa', 'imax468', 'oksana', 'extra'],
    'text': ['@raisa Bullshit!', 
             '@dnsTV2, are you kidding?', 
             '@dnsTV2 thanks to corona...', 
             '@oksana what do you mean by that???', 
             'raisa! It is so true!',
             'this row has now nicknames']
})

regexes = '|'.join(['@?' + re.escape(name) for name in df.name.str.replace('@', '')])
df['text2'] = df['text'].str.replace(regexes, '')
df

        name                                 text  \
0    @dnsTV2                     @raisa Bullshit!   
1  Sebastian            @dnsTV2, are you kidding?   
2     @raisa          @dnsTV2 thanks to corona...   
3    imax468  @oksana what do you mean by that???   
4     oksana                raisa! It is so true!   
5      extra           this row has no nicknames   

                          text2  
0                     Bullshit!  
1            , are you kidding?  
2           thanks to corona...  
3   what do you mean by that???  
4              ! It is so true!  
5    this row has no nicknames
```

Comment: Thank you! The first part is working well, but the second raises error. I get a problem with a row that does not contain any nicknames: 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/sre_parse.py in _parse(source, state, verbose, nested, first)
    646             if item[0][0] in _REPEATCODES:
    647                 raise source.error("multiple repeat",
--> 648                                    source.tell() - here + len(this))
    649             if item[0][0] is SUBPATTERN:
    650                 group, add_flags, del_flags, p = item[0][1]

error: multiple repeat at position 8

Comment: Hey @Elena. I updated my answer before I saw your comment. Give that a try. I also have an example in there now with no nicknames.

Comment: thank you! it works well with the example. when I start to apply it to the "real" df I'm working with (excel import in pandas) it stops at some point: 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/sre_parse.py in _parse(source, state, verbose, nested, first)
    646             if item[0][0] in _REPEATCODES:
    647                 raise source.error("multiple repeat",
--> 648                                    source.tell() - here + len(this))
    649             if item[0][0] is SUBPATTERN:
    650                 group, add_flags, del_flags, p = item[0][1]

error: multiple repeat at position 3455

Comment: Looks like you have names with `+`'s in them or something. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hi! I noticed that some names are common words combinations, so that after using regex the text becames extremely damaged. could you help me to adjust the regex so that it would only look at the beginning of a string? thank you in advance

Comment: Just change `'@?'` to `'^@?'`

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the quick response! I tried to insert ^ before both @ and before each (first and second) separatedly. Before both and the first @ the text was not proceeded at all, before second @ it took some time and the result was the names not deleted properly and text damaged (missing word combinations almost in every text. Any idea?